# Random BSOD after Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, bsod, window

After Windows Update last week I've been getting random BSOD once in a while. Some days I'm fine, some days it will crash once or twice. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: We need way more info.  What error codes are on the BSoDs?  Are they always the same or different?  Have you analyzed your (mini)dumps yet?

Comment: To start analyzing your BSOD: http://superuser.com/questions/171196/how-to-analyze-a-memory-dump-on-windows-after-a-blue-screen-error

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, 3 BSoDs in last two days on an previously stable system.  nothing obvious in the logs, still researching.

There do seem to be quite a few errors relating to Schannel which is something to do with SSL in my event log.  But i couldn't find  much info on how to trouble shoot these in the brief time I had to look into this yesterday.