# Windows 10 - DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE BSOD

Tags: memory, drivers, windows-10, crash, bsod

I recently upgraded my ASUS ROG G551JW to Windows 10 and I have been getting random blue screens of death.  Games have also not been running as fast as they should be and it seems that I have less memory than I actually have (16 GB of RAM).  These crashes are very frustrating as this is a relatively new computer and I don't want to reinstall Windows or buy another laptop.  I have an idea that this might be caused by Nvidia drivers but I made sure that all my drivers are up to date to avoid any possible errors. Here is the contents of the dump file from the latest crash:

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 120115-29593-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 12/1/2015 8:33:19 PM
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000009f
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000003
Parameter 2       : ffffe001`78bfb060
Parameter 3       : ffffd000`d592ace0
Parameter 4       : ffffe001`79619c60
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+14f4d0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.10240.16590 (th1_st1.151104-1714)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14f4d0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\120115-29593-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 1,176,416
Dump File Time    : 12/1/2015 8:35:13 PM
==================================================
```

Comment: You should use WinDbg to determine the real driver causing the problem.  There is an existing [question](http://superuser.com/questions/171196/how-to-analyze-a-memory-dump-on-windows-after-a-blue-screen-error/171220#171220) on this very site that explains in details how to use that tool.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the documentation on it.

Comment: share the dmp file (upload it to OneDrive and post a share link here) if you don't know how to use Windbg

Comment: where you able to use Windbg? If not and you need help, share the dmp so that I can take a look at it

Comment: I installed WinDbg but wasn't really able to make sense of the analysis.  Hopefully you can download this .dmp file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/1y4hxbcp5n9vob8/120515-20406-01.dmp

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the dmp.

Comment: have you tried a newer nVIDIA driver? Does it solve your issue?

Comment: have you ever tried a newer nVIDIA driver? Does it solve your issue? if yes, [accept the reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 3):

By [analyzing the dump](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) I see that the crash is caused by the nVIDIA GPU driver `nvlddmkm.sys`:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe001e655f060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd000345aace0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe001e724c730, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now ffffe001`e44ab040
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.17.amd64fre.th2_release.151121-2308

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  G551JW

SYSTEM_SKU:  ASUS-NotebookSKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0       

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  G551JW.202

BIOS_DATE:  01/16/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  G551JW

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0       

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

FAULTING_THREAD:  e44ab040

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a22

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1E'00000000 (cache) 1E'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  SearchUI.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFD000345AAFB0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8032a0c7dca to fffff8032a1bd1f6

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
04 dxgkrnl!DpiFdoHandleDevicePower
05 dxgkrnl!DpiDispatchPower
06 nvlddmkm
07 0x0
08 0x0
09 0x0
0a 0x0

5: kd> !podev ffffe001e655f060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject e6561720
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000023 AttachedDev ffffe001e6560210 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe001e655f7b0:
PowerFlags: 00000040 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=4
Dope: 00000000:
5: kd> !devstack ffffe001e6560210
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe001e4448140  \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffe001e4448290  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe001e4448110

> ffffe001e6560210  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe001e6498470  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe001e65601e0

  ffffe001e655f060  \Driver\pci        ffffe001e655f1b0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe001e655e010 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_139B&SUBSYS_185D1043&REV_A2\4&819bc9d&0&0008"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"

Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
Timestamp:        Sat Nov 14 06:44:20 2015
```

This is the driver for your `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M` (`PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_139B`). Disable the PCIe power savings in the Windows power saving options. Also try the latest [nVIDIA driver](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us). Maybe the driver also fixes your 960M crashes. Because I see SearchUI.exe as process, open the nVIDIA control panel and select that SearchUI.exe runs on the Intel HD graphic and not on the nvidia card.