# What is causing this Windows 10 blue screen (MEMORY_MANAGEMENT ntoskrnl.exe)?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I'm getting the following blue screen in Windows 10:

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 010216-40531-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 1/2/2016 8:13:36 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00041201
Parameter 2       : fffff6bf`fcdc6488
Parameter 3       : 20700001`1349e025
Parameter 4       : ffffe001`5a2bf8a0
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+14f4d0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.10240.16590 (th1_st1.151104-1714)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14f4d0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\010216-40531-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 266,288
Dump File Time    : 1/2/2016 8:24:35 PM
==================================================
```

I'm also getting similar errors with ntoskrnl.exe with the error "IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL".

Everything I've searched on this is very vague. I'm not very good at decoding these dumps. I ran MemTest86 and memory checked out. Any insight on what might be causing this?

I'm running Windows 10 on a Dell Latitude E6410.

EDIT: Dump file can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymZO0GUQAGENXA5QVNnTkt5UVU/view

Comment: You tell us since you have not given us the .dmp file.  Have you [analyzed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538058(v=vs.85).aspx) or [here](http://superuser.com/questions/171196/how-to-analyze-a-memory-dump-on-windows-after-a-blue-screen-error/171220#171220) the .dmp file in order to determine the cause yet?  One thing I noticed is your not using Version 1511/Threshold 2 of Windows 10, go ahead and update Windows 10, so that is the case.

Comment: If you want us to perform the analyze for you.  You have to provide us with the .dmp file, its preferred you do it for us,  then provide us the information so we can interpret it for you though.

Comment: Didn't realize this PC was behind on Windows version, so I'll update that.

Comment: The .dmp file you provided **did not** generated a `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` error but an entirely different error, [`Memory_Management"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557391(v=vs.85).aspx).  Can you supply us the correct .dmp file?

Comment: My question is regarding the memory management error. Did you read it? There is another bsod with the IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL error. If you need that dump I can upload it but that's not the error I'm investigating.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/236626-bsod-ntoskrnl-exe-memory-management.html

Comment: @RahulBasu: Throwing random solutions at a problem is very bad practice and a waste of time if dump information can be analysed and further inspected to come up with the appropriate solution that works in a reasonable amount of time. In medical terms, you are consulting from and referring to Doctor Google instead of learning about and diagnosing the actual cause.

Comment: @Moses: The more you upload the more we can use to diagnose. Audio uses interrupts, therefore it has a IRQL, in your dump it is given IRQL **`2`**. Your audio driver may very well suffer from what else is also given IRQL **`2`**. That dump may reveal more exactly what is going on.

Comment: @Moses, did you manage to resolve this? I'm experiencing similar BSOD's mainly while playing games and in all recent BSODs I see ntoskrnl.exe marked as "suspected" using BlueScreenView with bug check strings like `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` and `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`.

Comment: @Tagc unfortunately this was long enough ago that I cant remember how it was resolved. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

When doing Bugcheck Analysis it is important to **obtain and read all output**; not only that, you also need **multiple dumps to cross check** this output along other bug checks to avoid false positives.

Your dump reveals quite a bit, but not enough for a conclusion:

- **Unknown memory management error** (1a, parameter 1: 41201) occured.

  > [`MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
  >
  > ```
  > Arg1: 0000000000041201, The subtype of the bugcheck.
  > ```
- Classified to be **a driver fault** that occurred during execution of **`audiodg.exe`**.

  > ```
  > DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT
  >
  > PROCESS_NAME:  audiodg.exe
  > ```
- Produced while querying virtual memory **at the end of copying system service memory**.

  > ```
  > STACK_TEXT:  
  > nt!KeBugCheckEx
  > nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::'string'+0x122c8
  > nt!MiQueryAddressState+0x307
  > nt!MiQueryAddressSpan+0x139
  > nt!MmQueryVirtualMemory+0x648
  > nt!NtQueryVirtualMemory+0x25
  > nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
  > 0x00007ff9'bbdf37aa
  > ```

  **`0x00007ff9'bbdf37aa`** is of particular interest here, because that is what is where the chain of calls originates from. However, there is no information about that because **your system is not configured to take [complete memory dumps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969028)**:

  > `Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available`

It's also not yet guaranteed that every dump you get results in the same, that needs to be verified.

Until you have more information, you have way too much possible solutions to try. More dumps that contain more complete information will spare you the hassle to go through all that.

But if you have some time, here is an incomplete list with no guarantees:

- Remove and reinstall your audio drivers.
- Update all your drivers
- Run RAM tests.
- Replace the RAM out of precaution.
- Remove your antivirus and consider another one.
- Make sure you are clean of viruses, malware, ...
- Run `sfc /scannow` and Microsoft's SUR or DISM utility to check system health.
- Reinstall your operating system.
- Keep replacing hardware till the broken piece is gone.
- ...

Comment: Well, I've updated Windows to the latest build and turned on complete memory dumps, so if it occurs again I'll have a more accurate picture of what's going on.

Comment: The same BSOD occured again today. I'm uploading the complete memory dump, and the minidump is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BymZO0GUQAGES2VSbjh1QW5wRGc

Comment: @Moses: Waiting for the complete one.

Comment: @TomWijsman, How do you know "*Classified to be a driver fault that occurred during execution of audiodg.exe*"?

Comment: @Pacerier: The quote below it displays it as such

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive that it could be a driver conflict with your wireless card. Mostly from experience with this laptop and wireless NIC's I've seen in the field.

Try re-installing and updating the driver(s) from the device manager, I would not advise updating the bios through Windows because of the off chance of a BSOD occuring while the update is running. Driver Identifier is a great service for finding/updating drivers.

If you must, either check if you can install the BIOS update through a [FreeDOS live USB](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=D1DK3&fileId=3379268523&osCode=W764&productCode=latitude-e6410&languageCode=EN&categoryId=BI). I provided a link to the driver details page on Dell's website for that laptop for further details. Just navigate to the "Install Instructions" drop-down and check that out.

Also, [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1901977) is a link to a good guide on creating a FreeDOS live USB and installing the BIOS update.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You get the [Bug Check 0x1A: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The MEMORY_MANAGEMENT bug check has a value of 0x0000001A. This
>   indicates that a severe memory management error occurred.

From the callstack I can see that virtual memory operation where done:

```
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!MiQueryAddressState
03 nt!MiQueryAddressSpan
04 nt!MmQueryVirtualMemory
05 nt!NtQueryVirtualMemory
06 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
07 0x0
```

So, this looks like some RAM issues. If memtest86+ shows no errors, check the RAM timings. Run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), look into the tabs `Memory` and `SPD` and verify that the values match and that `Command Rate` is set to `2`. If Command Rate (CR) is set to 1, go to the BIOS and change it to 2.

Comment: Here's the memory page (https://i.imgur.com/CCG3ALx.png) and the SPD page (https://i.imgur.com/CCG3ALx.png). The Command Rate is set to 1T, but I don't see any option in the BIOS to change that.

Comment: you posted the memory tab twice.

Comment: Oops. SPD Tab: https://i.imgur.com/pgIsUO6.png

Comment: ok, the tRAS is defined with 21 in the SPD data, but your RAM runs at 19. this is bad. Look if you can change this value in the BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Unfortunately, my BIOS offers no settings for RAM at all.

Comment: in this case, try other RAM. Ask a friend who also uses a laptop if you can try 1 module of his RAM. If this one works, your RAM is faulty.

Comment: have you tried other RAM?