# VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR on clean installation windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

For the past month, my computer out of nowhere started giving me `VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR` blue screens, about 3 times a day. This occurs specifically while watching online videos of any kind, for example *YouTube* or *Twitch.tv*. I am using Google chrome (version `50.0.2661.102`). I have never crashed once while searching in Google and doing some programming in an IDE. I have also never crashed once while watching an offline video with a video player, like `MPC-HC`.

Today I did a clean install of windows 10 Education. 5 hours later, I got a blue screen `VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR` while watching a YouTube video. Windows 10 installed the default drivers for my graphics card automagically. Since I crashed with those, I then uninstalled them and installed the latest drives from the AMD's website (version `15.300.1025.1001`). However, the error persisted.

**GPU**

AMD Radeon R7 260X

**CPU**

Intel Core i7 2600 @ 3.40GHz Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology

**dxdiag**

[image: 5]

**BlueScreenViewer**

[image: 1]

**WinDBG**

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\shiro\Desktop\052516-5921-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 10240 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`bbe1a000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`bc13ef30
Debug session time: Wed May 25 01:25:07.867 2016 (UTC + 3:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:54:56.537
Loading Kernel Symbols
.

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

..............................................................
................................................................
.......................................
Loading User Symbols
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 119, {100000, 0, 1, ffffe000032b5000}

Probably caused by : dxgmms2.sys ( dxgmms2! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+74e )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

7: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR (119)
The video scheduler has detected that fatal violation has occurred. This resulted
in a condition that video scheduler can no longer progress. Any other values after
parameter 1 must be individually examined according to the subtype.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000100000, The subtype of the bugcheck:
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000001
Arg4: ffffe000032b5000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  F15

BIOS_DATE:  10/23/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  B75M-D3H

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 100000

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 1

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe000032b5000

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: d40

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 2a

CPU_STEPPING: 7

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,2a,7,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 29'00000000 (cache) 29'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x119

PROCESS_NAME:  dwm.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-17V3BKR

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  05-25-2016 18:56:19.0673

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80034603c3d to fffff801bbf66c20

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`93632a58 fffff800`34603c3d : 00000000`00000119 00000000`00100000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd000`93632a60 fffff800`3612675e : 00000000`0086f249 ffffe000`0665ace0 00000000`00000000 ffffc000`ea7a2170 : watchdog!WdLogEvent5_WdCriticalError+0xcd
ffffd000`93632aa0 fffff800`34691575 : ffffc000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`93632fb0 ffffc000`ea7a2170 : dxgmms2! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x74e
ffffd000`93632b10 fffff800`346924be : ffffe000`05ca1e80 ffffc000`dd5e0010 ffffc000`dd5e0010 ffffc000`dca92000 : dxgkrnl!DXGCONTEXT::SubmitPresent+0x7c5
ffffd000`93632e90 fffff800`346905ba : ffffe000`05cc7010 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : dxgkrnl!DXGCONTEXT::Present+0xd9e
ffffd000`93633900 fffff801`bbf71263 : 0000004e`08b0cbf0 ffffe000`0672c080 0000004e`00000000 00000000`00000020 : dxgkrnl!DxgkPresent+0x63a
ffffd000`93633b00 00007ffc`ce87f52a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
0000004e`08b0cb88 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`ce87f52a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  412dd47eac85582193e38764b63229bcc8b9f206

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  4bb19553b608cadfaf31fbc0b7a31fab134acd40

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  64c1c03a80525e517952b5ed45d7da9933421bd7

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
dxgmms2! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+74e
fffff800`3612675e cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  858b41cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  dxgmms2! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+74e

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: dxgmms2

IMAGE_NAME:  dxgmms2.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  559f3b7b

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10240.16384

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  74e

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x119_100000_UNKNOWN_dxgmms2!_??_::NNGAKEGL::_string_

BUCKET_ID:  0x119_100000_UNKNOWN_dxgmms2!_??_::NNGAKEGL::_string_

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x119_100000_UNKNOWN_dxgmms2!_??_::NNGAKEGL::_string_

TARGET_TIME:  2016-05-24T22:25:07.000Z

OSBUILD:  10240

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2015-07-10 06:29:30

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  150709-1700

BUILDLAB_STR:  th1

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 3f0

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x119_100000_unknown_dxgmms2!_??_::nngakegl::_string_

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ce933178-2d4b-395b-88bf-dffbd8e28457}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

7: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR (119)
The video scheduler has detected that fatal violation has occurred. This resulted
in a condition that video scheduler can no longer progress. Any other values after
parameter 1 must be individually examined according to the subtype.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000100000, The subtype of the bugcheck:
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000001
Arg4: ffffe000032b5000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  F15

BIOS_DATE:  10/23/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  B75M-D3H

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 100000

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 1

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe000032b5000

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: d40

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 2a

CPU_STEPPING: 7

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,2a,7,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 29'00000000 (cache) 29'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x119

PROCESS_NAME:  dwm.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-17V3BKR

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  05-25-2016 18:56:20.0682

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80034603c3d to fffff801bbf66c20

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`93632a58 fffff800`34603c3d : 00000000`00000119 00000000`00100000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd000`93632a60 fffff800`3612675e : 00000000`0086f249 ffffe000`0665ace0 00000000`00000000 ffffc000`ea7a2170 : watchdog!WdLogEvent5_WdCriticalError+0xcd
ffffd000`93632aa0 fffff800`34691575 : ffffc000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`93632fb0 ffffc000`ea7a2170 : dxgmms2! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x74e
ffffd000`93632b10 fffff800`346924be : ffffe000`05ca1e80 ffffc000`dd5e0010 ffffc000`dd5e0010 ffffc000`dca92000 : dxgkrnl!DXGCONTEXT::SubmitPresent+0x7c5
ffffd000`93632e90 fffff800`346905ba : ffffe000`05cc7010 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : dxgkrnl!DXGCONTEXT::Present+0xd9e
ffffd000`93633900 fffff801`bbf71263 : 0000004e`08b0cbf0 ffffe000`0672c080 0000004e`00000000 00000000`00000020 : dxgkrnl!DxgkPresent+0x63a
ffffd000`93633b00 00007ffc`ce87f52a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
0000004e`08b0cb88 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`ce87f52a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  412dd47eac85582193e38764b63229bcc8b9f206

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  4bb19553b608cadfaf31fbc0b7a31fab134acd40

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  64c1c03a80525e517952b5ed45d7da9933421bd7

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
dxgmms2! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+74e
fffff800`3612675e cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  858b41cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  dxgmms2! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+74e

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: dxgmms2

IMAGE_NAME:  dxgmms2.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  559f3b7b

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10240.16384

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  74e

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x119_100000_UNKNOWN_dxgmms2!_??_::NNGAKEGL::_string_

BUCKET_ID:  0x119_100000_UNKNOWN_dxgmms2!_??_::NNGAKEGL::_string_

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x119_100000_UNKNOWN_dxgmms2!_??_::NNGAKEGL::_string_

TARGET_TIME:  2016-05-24T22:25:07.000Z

OSBUILD:  10240

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2015-07-10 06:29:30

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  150709-1700

BUILDLAB_STR:  th1

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 3f2

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x119_100000_unknown_dxgmms2!_??_::nngakegl::_string_

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ce933178-2d4b-395b-88bf-dffbd8e28457}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: I want you to use windbg on the crashes your interested about, and post the analsys information, on those crashes.  [How you use windbg to determine the driver causing a BSOD is well documented.](http://superuser.com/questions/171196/how-to-analyze-a-memory-dump-on-windows-after-a-blue-screen-error/171220#171220).  The information i am asking for is vital, I can't submit an answer, without it.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the current 10586 build of Windows 10. You are still running 10240.  If you perform a [selective minimal boot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) configuration does the crash still itself?  So `dxgmms2.sys` is causing the crash not `watchdog.sys`.  So can you also post the dxdiag report?

Comment: @Ramhound Since I installed windows 10 education yesterday I suppose windows haven't updated anything yet. I clicked `check for updates` just now so I will be waiting for those to be downloaded and installed. However, I have used the same version of this OS 5 months ago, and I never had those problems. They randomly appeared out of nowhere and they persist on a CLEAN installation of windows 10. I will have to test the minimal boost configuration as well I suppose. This will take time. I can't reproduce the BSOD on command.

Comment: @Shiro - Around 5 months ago the current version was indeed 10240, 10586 was released in Nov 2015.  If you can't reproduce the crash we can't really help you.

Comment: @Ramhound I have had 5 blue screens in 24 hours. The crash happens randomly when watching online videos.

Comment: So you do have a way to reproduce it.  What Intel CPU do you have?  Be sure you provide the dxdiag reports and try performing that upgrade to 10586

Comment: @Ramhound The only way I see of upgrading windows is through `check for updates` which is currently derping around at 0% download and not going up. I will put those info on the question itself.

Comment: I wanted the dxdiag report not whatever you provided, be sure you update your Intel GPU drivers, if you have them installed

Answer (score 0):

With this super old driver `amd-catalyst-14-9-win7-win8.1-64bit-dd-ccc-whql.exe` I have never crashed again. This driver I downloaded when I bought the video card and I luckily still had it on my computer.

All the latest drivers in AMD's website are causing my computer to crash when streaming videos in a browser. It is an absolute mess.