# windows 7 blue screen crash in ks.sys

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, bsod, crash

I upgraded my 250GB SSD drive to a PNY 480 SSD drive and added one more external monitor few days ago. It seems no problem until today I got twice **blue screen** crashes. There three crashes since yesterday at the same place. What I can do for this? It happened during the process of wake up. [image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have installed the latest driver for that **new dell monitor** which is connected with my computer via a **mini-displayPort cable** (which is new to the computer as well). That new monitor driver desn't help.

dump file links:

[dumpFile1](http://wikisend.com/download/948014/020317-9188-01.dmp)

[dumpFile2](http://wikisend.com/download/390118/020217-9796-01.dmp)

[dumpFile3](http://wikisend.com/download/558554/013117-9937-01.dmp)

Comment: BlueScreenView is notorious for pointing to the wrong file.  The only true way to find the problem file is with windbg.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/171196/how-to-analyze-a-memory-dump-on-windows-after-a-blue-screen-error/171220#171220

Comment: Making a minidump available may be useful.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558949(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: update webcam driver and if this doesn't help, share the dumps so that we can analyze them

Comment: have you uploaded the dump files?

Comment: windows crashes at the function ks!KspPinPropertyHandler which is not helpful. updates all drivers on our PC