# What is causing these BSODs?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

My PC has had an issue with BSODs for most of the time I've had it. Most of them are Critical Process Died, usually svchost.exe or services.exe. Today, it crashed with Unexpected Store Exception. I built this PC in July of 2019. I have reset this PC twice since then, and the problem has persisted. Since the last time, the PC has been reset, I have had 6 BSODs, usually two in a day. The following are the BSODs and the time the dump file was written:

- 5-11-2020 06:35
- CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED
- 5-11-2020 06:39
- CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED
- 5-20-2020 10:12
- CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED
- 5-20-2020 11:59
- Crashdump file failed to write.
- 5-26-2020 10:58
- UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION

I suspect that there is a bug in my current version of Windows or that I have corrupted system files. Can anyone give insight as to what is causing these BSODs? I am tracking the crashdumps with Git and have a public repo for them [here](https://github.com/AwesomeCronk/CrashDumps).

Windows version: Windows 10 Home build 10.0.18362 x64
Motherboard: Gigabyte h110-d3a
CPU: Intel Pentium G4560
GPU: MSI GeForce GTX 1650
Boot Drive: Seagate Barracuda 1TB ST1000DM010
RAM: GSkill Aegis DDR4 F4-2400C15S-8GIS 8GB 2 sticks
WiFi adapter: TPLink TL-WN881ND
DVD/CD-RAM: LG M-DISC

Information update: I suspect the Graphics driver may be to blame. I was running a DirectX 11 game (Space Engineers by Keen Software House) when the game froze up and reported a graphics driver crash. Windows itself did not crash, however, just the game. I have the game's log file added to the git repo. Noticing that the NVidia driver was present in all of the crash dumps and is what crashed here, I am going to look into replacing the driver. My GPU did not come with a disk, however, so I will need to do some research.

Comment: I really don't know if this only has a single cause, but I recently had the `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED` over & over until I replaced my SATA cable.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: For additional detail - I also discovered that, in common with many badly-designed PC cases, putting the side of the case on would just press sufficiently on the SATA plug in the HD socket that it would generate these spurious errors. I eventually swapped for a 90° cable which took the pressure off it.

Comment: Also, (a) Update BIOS and all other drivers (Manufacturer's driver update application, and (b) create a bootable USB Key. Load the USB key, run a browser from it, pound away and see if it crashes. Try this a couple of times and if it crashes - hardware and if not - some bug in your OS.

Comment: I don't have to even analyze the files with [windbg](https://superuser.com/questions/171196/how-to-analyze-a-memory-dump-on-windows-after-a-blue-screen-error/171220#171220) to determine the BSOD is not caused by a bug within Windows.  The chances those BSOD are due to a undiscovered bug is extremely small.  If you run `windbg` yourself and provide the outputs to your repository somebody might be look at the results.  What is more likely is there is a device driver that is not behaving itself.  *If it was a bug it would have been discovered within the last year by somebody.*

Comment: Make and specific model of PC?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to provide an answer but then for space and presentation, this is the information so far - There are 4 dump files, in chronological order they are:

1. 051120-24312-01.dmp

   > Mon May 11 12:32:50.165 2020 (UTC + 1:00)
   >
   > System Uptime: 0 days 0:08:51.857
   >
   > CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED  (services.exe)
   >
   > PROCESS_NAME:  services.exe (stack for a thread in services.exe (proc 0) terminated itself)
2. 051120-24593-01.dmp

   > Mon May 11 12:38:39.934 2020 (UTC + 1:00)
   >
   > System Uptime: 0 days 0:05:21.627
   >
   > CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED  (services.exe)
   >
   > PROCESS_NAME:  services.exe (stack for a thread in services.exe (proc 0) terminated itself)
3. 052020-24140-01.dmp

   > Wed May 20 16:10:56.947 2020 (UTC + 1:00)
   >
   > System Uptime: 0 days 0:36:27.640
   >
   > CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED  (services.exe)
   >
   > PROCESS_NAME:  services.exe (stack for a thread in services.exe (proc 2) terminated itself)
4. 052620-27031-01.dmp

   > Tue May 26 16:53:04.515 2020 (UTC + 1:00)
   >
   > System Uptime: 0 days 0:30:57.208
   >
   > UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION
   >
   > PROCESS_NAME:  MemCompression

As for drivers that we can't obtain symbols for, let's make the assumption that Microsoft drivers are without fault, all dumps have Virtual Box drivers, dump 3 has Defender and 4 has Malwarebytes. It's hard to believe that Malwarebytes has shifted the bugcheck from CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED to UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION.

Given that Virtual Box drivers are in all 4 dumps, one option might be to uninstall it.  The drivers seem very recent.  While that is typically a good thing, new bugs can be introduced.

> VBoxNetLwf  - Thu Apr  9 19:01:32 2020
>   VBoxUSBMon  - Thu Apr  9 19:01:32 2020
>   VBoxDrv     - Thu Apr  9 19:02:18 2020
>   VBoxNetAdp6 - Thu Apr  9 19:01:32 2020

The other drivers that are common between all dumps are Realtek (RTKVHD64, rt640x64) and Nvidia (nvhda64v, nvlddmkm) which are typically pretty good and hard to believe they are likely to be causing an issue.

At this point, I think the best thing you can do is run Verifier.exe and choose:

> Create Standard Settings
>
> Select driver Names from a list
>
> Choose the following.
>
> VBoxNetLwf.sys
>   VBoxUSBMon.sys
>   VBoxDrv.sys
>   VBoxNetAdp6.sys
>   rt640x64.sys
>   nvhda64v.sys
>   nvlddmkm.sys
>   RTKVHD64.sys

Complete the wizard and restart.  Hopefully the next dump will be more conclusive and you can link that. It seems to bugcheck within 30 minutes of starting.

Note: Don't forget to run Verifier again to disable the monitoring of these drivers once complete.

Comment: Wow. I will do this as soon as I can get back to the computer. What tools did you use to analyze the crash dumps?

Comment: @AwesomeCronk - Just WinDbg Preview from the store.  Also worth getting and loading the Microsoft MEX extension.  It might be possible to learn more with a complete dump but I'm interested to see with verifier enabled what the next dump might look like.

Comment: I have more information on the subject added above. Does Verifier.exe inspect drivers that crash only at BSOD or at any time?