# Windows not starting blue screen of death

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I have a laptop with me which has Windows XP operating system installed in it.

- The problem is that after boot logo my Windows XP shows blue screen of death.
- I can start windows only in safe mode.
- And the main problem is that whenever I scan with malwarebytes or scan it starts but while scanning it vanishes and when I again start the any of this two programs an error pop up saying that "Cannot find the path of the software".
- Is there any way to remove this blue screen of death.

Comment: You need to update this question with specific information about specific your blue screen error, have a look at some guides on how to diagnose blue screen errors: http://superuser.com/questions/28448/how-to-diagnose-blue-screens-in-windows-7-64bit

Comment: Do not waste time in trying to solve the issue. Just re-install windows.

Comment: @Kaustubh bluescreens can be caused by a lot of things. Perhaps a recent driver update broke things, and reinstalling would bring back the same problem. Maybe it's being caused by gradual hardware failure. Reinstalling is not the answer to everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many BSOD, some related to bad drivers, some related to software conflict and some related to hardware, but the latest spywares/viruses give you I believe the BSOD error: 0x7E.
It looks like you are having a severe spyware or rootkit (or as MBR infection).
I would first try to download: TDSSKILLER
http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208280684

if it doesn't work, try Kaspsersky Virus Removal Tool:
http://www.kaspersky.com/antivirus-removal-tool?form=1

Let us know if it works for you.