# Blue Screen: Driver_Irql_not_less_or_Equal and System_Service_Exception

Tags: windows-7

The following two blue screens happened on my computer recently. They both displayed two different messages:

1) Driver_Irql_not_less_or_Equal
2) System_Service_exception

After the first one, ran an anti-virus and anti-malware but the second blue screen happened (OS: Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1).

I have checked several websites but could not find a solution yet.

[image: Blue Scrren 1]

[image: BlueScreen 2]

Comment: Lets start by you reading some basic ways to figure out what might be causing it and using some tools to expand the information you have provied. http://superuser.com/questions/28448/how-to-diagnose-blue-screens-in-windows-7-64bit?rq=1 The underline cause per the Microsoft documentation is a driver. Be sure you attampt to load Windows so netw5s64.sys isn't used ( provided thats not a required system Windows file ).  I had no problem finding the cause of your BSOD: http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/248407-bsod-driver_irql_not_less_or_equal-netw5s64.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The netw5s64.sys is an Intel Wifi driver. So get the [latest driver from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=intel%20Wifi%20Link%201000) and look if this fixes it.

The new dump shows that it can be caused by Avast (aswSnx.sys):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff80002f59990, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffff8800b568130, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002f2043a to fffff80002f59990

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiSystemServiceHandler
nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
nt!RtlDispatchException
nt!KiDispatchException
nt!KiExceptionDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
nt!RtlCompareUnicodeStrings
nt!RtlCompareUnicodeString
aswSnx
0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  aswSnx.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x3B_aswSnx+2cb3a

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x3B_aswSnx+2cb3a

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x3b_aswsnx+2cb3a

    Loaded symbol image file: aswSnx.sys
    Image path: \??\C:\Windows\system32\drivers\aswSnx.sys
    Image name: aswSnx.sys
    Timestamp:        Mon Oct 14 19:01:10 2013
```

Comment: ntoskrnl.exe ntoskrnl.exe+594a0 fffff800`03a12000 fffff800`03ff7000 0x005e5000 0x521ea035 29/08/2013 01:13:25 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System NT Kernel & System 6.1.7601.18247 (win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532) Microsoft Corporation C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani this doesn't help. I need the real DMP files. upload them (skydrive, dropbox)

Comment: please see dmp file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9pkq3mi4jm6w03e/110913-19328-01.dmp

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani I've updated my answer.