# A variety of PC problems including blue screens and failure to boot

Tags: windows-7, bsod, troubleshooting, gaming

I recently rebuilt my gaming PC.

- I used the same hard drives and ram, but everything else is brand new.
- I reinstalled windows and everything was great for about a month.

Recently, I had a BSOD which said something like IRQL_LESS_OR_NOT_EQUAL. I have had this error before so I did what I did then; remove a stick of ram, but there was a problem. The computer would not boot and the VGA_LED was on. Okay, what about the other one.

Now it boots, but I have had a variety of blue screens trying to get it to boot this way. 7e, 1e, and a KERNEL_APC_PENDING_DURING_EXIT.

I have tried booting into safe mode but I get blue screens there, too.

I have also tried just reinstalling but that freezes at the "starting windows" animation.

Here's a what BlueScreenView said: [pastebin.com/UkcqE9FE](http://www.pastebin.com/UkcqE9FE)

Specs: Asus M5A99FX PRO R 2.0 mobo AMD FX 8350 processor Corsair CX750 PSU Nvidia GTX 970 GPU 16 GB Signature RAM WD 320 GB blue HDD (OS) WD 2 TB green HDD

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You have not really provided any information that is helpful, at least information, that could generate a well documented explanation.

Comment: Are you certain the hardware you bought is compatible with the motherboard you have?

Comment: @Ramhound, my question is how can I get my computer back to working condition and what other information or tests can I get or preform?

Comment: @Terry yes, I am certain. My PC was working for several weeks, but now I cannot get it into working condition. I bought a new motherboard when I bought all of the new parts and I had an expert help me with my decision.

Comment: You have not provided the information required to explain how to solve your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, can you help me out with that? What other information should I give? I'm not really sure what else to give.

Comment: We've seen this behavior before, even though it worked for a small period of time. Check if you can upgrade your BIOS (should be possible from a bootable USB).

Comment: @Terry, okay, I will try that.

Comment: [You had multiple BSOD events, but you don't indicate, what you have done to determine the cause of those BSOD events.](http://superuser.com/questions/28448/how-to-diagnose-blue-screens-in-windows-7-64bit?rq=1).  You just giving us the vague overall description of the crash is not enough information to explain what actually is going on.

Comment: @Ramhound, I would love to run some BSOD diagnostic or analysis tool, but I can't really get my PC to boot in any manner whatsoever.

Comment: You can extract the data files generated by the BSODs off your HDD and then determine the cause of the crashes.

Comment: @Ramhound, Okay, I will get that after I try updating the BIOS, thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I updated the bios and no luck. I got a 1A blue screen when I tried booting into safe mode. I am going to try to see what I can get out of those BSOD files.

Comment: Here's a what BlueScreenView said:

http://pastebin.com/UkcqE9FE

Comment: Have you tried running your computer without the graphics card? Could be that the drivers are out of date/incompatible. Its worth a go. Just pop the card out and try onboard graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my one stick of "working" RAM with a stick from a friend and everything seemed to be back in working condition. My solution is, unfortunately, to shell out $60 for some new RAM. Thanks, guys.