# Rebuilt computer blue screens differently and sporadically every start up

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, nvidia-graphics-card

I lived in the US and moved to Australia,  and took my computer with me.  To ship it  I had to take it completely apart  and couldn't bring the original power source.

So I purchased a new power supply,  put together the parts (Asus motherboard,  Intel processor,  32gb ram, two Nvidia quadro graphics cards)

At first it wasn't booting,  but I fixed that and it was fine for a few days,  but then randomly it started having issues starting.  Either in the middle of booting or right after loading the desktop it's gives me bluescreen messages (in Windows 10) like 'Memory management' and 'thread stuck in device driver'

What do these errors mean,  and what sort of stuff should I do to fix it? I'm leaning towards it being a graphics card issue,  but I've completely disassembled and reassembled this computer about five times now trying to see if I could fix it.  The problem definitely stops when the graphics cards are both out

Comment: Grab a copy of [whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) or [blue screen view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) The former does semi automated crash analysis and should get you started. The latter would allow you to more precisely say what the error is. Blue screen view would also let you examine the dumps from another machine so you can copy it over.

Comment: In addition, feels like its the quadros or the driver. Is the driver updated to the latest version? Do the quadros have power inputs, and are they somehow connected differently from the old one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose Blue Screens in Windows 7 (64bit)](http://superuser.com/questions/28448/how-to-diagnose-blue-screens-in-windows-7-64bit)